# C# ASP.NET Retrieving thousands of Active Directory records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, active-directory

I need to display in a Report a list of users along with their full names and email addresses that match certain criteria for an application that is running in our domain. The current application that I will be reporting of already knows all of the Active Directory "Usernames", but "Display Name" and "Email address" for each one of the users are not present in the application database.

These reports could potentially contain up to 25k records, and I am not sure how efficient will it be to query Active Directory for 25k records (only displayname and email will be queried), or instead query the local database for those fields. These reports may be ran daily (up to 10x in one day).

Here is the question, should I add a table to the application's database and run an overnight script to populate a table with each username, display name and email address for each of the application users? (approximately 25,000 users), or should I query Active Directory for those fields every time a report is requested, which ultimately pull up to 250,000 the usernames and email addresses of the users in these reports?

Thanks

Comment: About one year ago my team and I faced the same situation. We ended up pulling from AD once a week and updating the app's database, and then just query from the app's DB. We talked to HHRR and the told us that they don't even hire new employees every day anyways, so updating the DB every day was useless.

Comment: Similar situation here. I pull in about 20k records from AD for a line of business every 15 minutes. The pulled data is stored in SQL server for archiving and comparison.

Answer (score 2):

AD is usually of vital importance to an organisation and I would think twice about introducing a process that's going to pull 250,000 records from it every time someone runs a report. At best you're going to upset the network administrators and at worst you're going to stop users logging in, downloading patches etc.

Overnight job would be preferable (IMHO) and then you have a little bit more work to get the data into the report but it will be worth it in the long run.